# Dimensional model with textual keys vs integer keys

Tags: powerbi

I have fact table that links to dimension table via a textual column (instead of id).

In Power BI model, does it make any performance difference whether I use the key relation between fact and dimension table on an integer column.

Example:

```
fact.product_id joins dimension.product_id
```

Versus using textual value.

Example:

```
fact.product_name joins dimension.product_name
```

Comment: I'd suspect that the engine indexes text relationships under the hood as an internal optimization but I don't have documentation supporting this conjecture at the moment.

Comment: Integer columns probably take up less space and will perform faster in joins - but whether that is measurable or has any material impact is unlikely (but obviously dependent on your particular circumstances). However, the reasons why dimensional modelling uses integer surrogate keys rather than source system business keys has little to do with performance

Comment: Comparing strings is very complex operation. It isn't a binary comparison - think about collations, case (in)sensitivity, etc. Whenever possible, use numeric keys.